# I scammed my best friend but now I'm feeling sorry about it

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

Unicoins have always been precious to me, somehow too precious since I even scammed my best friend to get his unicoins.

I told him I had a real unicorn and had him buy my dog with a paper horn on the head in exchange for all his unicoins

[image]

Now after a week he realized that my dog isn't a unicorn (the glue on the dog's head is starting to loose) and wants his unicoins back.

I feel bad about it since I cheated on my best friend, is there anything I can do to make things right again?

Comment: What? Seriously wtf is this?

Comment: I'm ashamed of what I've done to get unicoins.  Ashamed.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait...you're saying that *isn't* a real unicorn? Nothing makes sense anymore

Comment: @codeMagic I was joking!!! it is a real unicorn! I'll trade it to you in exchange for your unicoins..

Comment: Thanks, I would but I just bought one from Blue Ice but maybe after some more mining. Now, if I can just get it away from my wife...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper thing to do would be to ask to exchange the dog with a unicorn horn with this:

[image: unicat]

It's a unicorn, right? Nobody will know the difference.

Comment: Are you *sure* that thing is a unicorn horn >.< ?

Comment: rated 18+: I am afraid women's may misuse this little kitty...

Comment: Cat does not look like it's loving it.

Answer (score 7):

Try sticking a horn on a Potato.. and tell him that he can actually make unichips or *unitato chips* out of it... See if that makes him happy

### They are delicious, trust me

[image]

Comment: I... don't... even... but I am hungry! Stolen for my next non-unicorn-themed avatar.

Comment: I'd buy that for a unicoin!

Comment: Don't eat me! Are you seriously saying this?

Comment: @Unitato rofl xD

Answer (score 5):

Your friend will probably understand that the unicorn purchase was made in poor taste. You may have to give a refund in 6 to 8 weeks.

Your dog however, will never forgive you. Not only were his hopes and dreams dashed from believing that he, just a good-ole-boy, could be a unicorn, but you freaking sold him!

You sold your best friend for unicoins. That is as bad as posting on meta on April fools and not even making a reference to waffles or rainbows.

Comment: Aaaah! I've been taking meta too seriously the entire time!